# Get AVAudioSession properties of embedded YouTube Player

Tags: iphone, swift, audio, youtube, ios9

Is it possible to get properties (for example, the averagePowerForChannel data) from an instance of audio provided by the mobile YouTube player on iOS 9? I have a youtube player in an iframe (using their API) embedded in a UIWebView, but how would I go about accessing the audio session data?

I'd like to do this to create an audio visualiser based on audio output from YouTube. I'm doing this all in Swift 2.

Thanks!